# База данных фильмов на русском

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Пытался найти в гугле, но там либо какой-то софт для хранения инфы о просмотренных фильмах, либо мануалы по настройке. Может ищу неправильно, не знаю.

Использую PostgreSQL. Мне нужна БД с уже заполненными таблицами с описанием фильмов, желательно ещё и с постерами (не обязательно BLOB внутри БД, главное чтобы можно было легко слинковать информацию в БД с пикчей в директории, к примеру).

Нашёл только вот этот файл (в архиве архив, а в нём файл 24.sql): https://yadi.sk/d/pduURVBVqfvDK

Но при попытке импортировать через pgAdmin выдаёт ошибку: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Даже прочесть ошибку не могу =/

При попытке ввести команду в консоли вручную:

```
>pg_restore.exe --host "54.171.54.234" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --no-password --dbname "recommenderdb" --verbose "C:\\Users\\kamil\\Downloads\24.sql"
pg_restore: [архиватор] входной файл не похож на архив
```

Comment: SQL надо в `psql` отправлять.

Comment: @D-side а можно чуть подробнее - как это сделать?

Comment: Можно. Гляньте на [документацию `pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-pgdump.html#PG-DUMP-EXAMPLES), один из форматов вывода которого -- голый SQL.

Comment: @D-side пришло в голову открыть файл в редкторе и оказалось, что это просто набор SQL команд. причем формат неподходящий для PostgreSQL, как я понял: `INSERT INTO \`table30\` (\`id\`, \`duration\`,\`genre\`,\`title\`,\`year\`) VALUES ("797", "136 мин","11","Без лица","1997");` или так и должно быть?

Comment: Судя по бэктикам, оно для MySQL.

Comment: @D-side в любом случае, вот такой запрос `psql --host "54.171.54.234" --port "5432" --username "webapp" recommenderdb < "C:\\Users\\kamil\\Downloads\24.sql"` посыпал кучу синтаксических ошибок

Comment: @D-side можно это как-то исправить? конвертировать в подходящий для PostgreSQL формат?

Comment: Я бы, наверное, копал в сторону импорта в MySQL и экспорт его средствами в каком-нибудь более переносимом формате (стандартный SQL? JSON? JSONL?).

Comment: @D-side блин.. теперь ещё MySQL ставить =( а случайно не знаете, где можно достать готовую БД, которую можно было бы испортировать в PostgreSQL?

Comment: Не, не знаю. Но данные это самая тяжёлая часть. Преобразовать данные такого объёма плёвое дело.

Comment: для начала убрать обратные апострофы и заменить двойные кавычки на одинарные. только надо убедиться что внутри строк нет кавычек и если есть смотреть как они заэскеплены и если что то лишнее убирать, недостающее добавлять. В общем после просмотра и анализа встечающихся комбинаций кавычек поколдовать в regex101.com

Comment: @Mike вообще убрать или заменить на одинарные кавычки?

Comment: Обратные - убрать, там имена колонок не конфликтуют с зарезервированными словами SQL и заключать их в какие либо кавычки не надо. Вы с синтаскисом insert в postgesql вообще знакомы ?